# Cannot resolve symbol 'imageView'

Tags: android

Can anyone check why its no resolving symbol "imageView" at this :
`imageView= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);`

Here is the full code :

```
public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    
    public TextView txtMenuName;
    public ImageView imageView;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public MenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtMenuName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
        **imageView= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);**

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, _which_ `imageView` is it not resolving? The variable or the id?

Comment: I dont have any id for imageView so i guess the variable

Comment: @FoxAli Check the ImageView class import and run Clean -> Build from Build menu of android studio.

Comment: _"I dont have any id for imageView"_ Then why are you trying to use `R.id.imageView`?

Comment: Btw. it is not a full code. You haven't attached XML for Recycler item and it is probably located there because you've created instance of `ImageView` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using findViewById without having an “imageView” id in your xml layout.

Just add an id for your imageView and you are good to go.

```
<ImageView 
 ..
 ..
 android:id=“@+id/imageView”
 ..
 ..
/>
```

Comment: awesome bro thats it !

Answer (score 0):

Set the Id to your image view. For example, it looks like this:

```
<ImageView 
...
android:id="@+id/imageView"
...
/>
```